# Careers Page shows Authorization Required

Tags: support, bug, status-completed, jobs

I was browsing through the Careers page and found a `Authentication Required` box on this Front-end Developer position: [Social Care Network](http://careers.stackoverflow.com/jobs/90032/front-end-developer-social-care-network?utm_source=stackoverflow.com&utm_medium=ad&utm_campaign=small-sidebar-orange-looking)

[image: Authorization Required]

Seems like .htpasswd appended with the content as well :P Not sure why does this show up?

Comment: Looks like the logo they're trying to use is linked from an inaccessible location, whoops.

Comment: @Manoj Which browser/OS are you using?

Comment: I am using Firefox 38.0.5/Windows 7

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This issue is related to the company logo, the loading of which requires authentication. I have removed the logo for now, so the prompt box will not appear anymore. We'll get in touch with the company to make them aware of the logo issue.

Thanks for the report!

Comment: Thanks for the update guys. The page looks much better now :D